# Syntax error on token "default", StringLiteral expected

Tags: eclipse, mongoose, syntax-error, default

I'm working with Mongo - Mongoose on Eclipse IDE, and I'm trying to make a default value for a schema, as in the example:

```
myNum: { type: Number, default: 1 },
myDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
```

but it seems that ***default*** is a saved word, so I get:

> ***Syntax error on token "default", StringLiteral expected***

I guess it's an error generated by eclipse - how do I bypass it?

Answer (score 1):

surrounding the 'default' word in '' solves it:

```
myNum: { type: Number, 'default': 1 },
myDate: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
```